# I want to override AbstractTemplate.php of vendor\magento\module-email\Model\

Tags: magento-2.1, abstract-class

I want to override AbstractTemplate.php of vendor\magento\module-email\Model\ in magento 2.1.12.I want to change getUrl method which are declare in AbstractTemplate.php.How can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override `AbstractTemplate.php of vendor\magento\module-email\Model\`

`Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate` is an abstract class and it never gets instantiated.

you can  override the `template.php  of vendor\magento\module-email\Model\`

adding this
`function public function setForcedArea($templateId)
    {
        if (!isset($this->area)) {
            $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
        }
        return $this;
    }`
and issue resolved.after that you can  easily select the theme after overriding the `template.php` file .

here is complete override module you can download here and solve your problem 
https://github.com/hafizjee/Area-code-is-already-set

Comment: This is the correct answer as all the others go off into the standard Plugin or Rewrrite process and no one noticed the class is `abstract` and therefor not overridable. The question asks for override/rewrite not plugin around / replacment. Thanks Hafiz, you also solved my related problem (I also failed to notice the abstract keyword! D'oh!)

Answer (score 0):

You need use plugin , example :

> di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate">
        <plugin name="my_product_url_path_generator" type="Namespace\Module\Model\PLugin\AbstractTemplate" sortOrder="99999"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\AbstractTemplate.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin;


    class AbstractTemplate 
    {
        //code , maby __construct()
        public function afterGetUrl(\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate $subject,$path)
        {
            //YOUR CODE change $path
            return $path

        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case,Registeration.php or module.xml is required or not.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you want to change the behavior of getUrl() function. So my suggestion to define a [Plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) over  `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate`.

On this plugin use  Before method `beforeGetUrl()` or after Method `afterGetUrl()` or `aroundGetUrl()` as per as your requirement.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

So, You should define plugin using  **`di.xml`** at `app\code\{Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate">
        <plugin name="change_url_value" sortOrder="1"
                type="{Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\Plugin\Email\AbstractTemplatPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Suppose,i have use around method

```
<?php

namespace {Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\Plugin\Email;

class AbstractTemplatPlugin 
{

    public function aroundGetUrl(
        \Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate $subject,
        \closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store,
     $route = '',
     $params = []   
    ) {
    // set $url from here
        return  $url;
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case,Registeration.php or module.xml is required or not.

Comment: offcoruce they have also required also composer.json

Comment: I will echo some messsage,but this is not showing.what is issue?

Comment: donot use echo under it, use x-debug for debugging purpose

Comment: i want to redirect custom forgetpassword page with parameters id and token on angular frontend using this getUrl method.