# I want to override vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php

Tags: magento2.2, override-model

I want to override method `setForcedArea()` because I'm using Magento 2.2.4 & whenever I tried to save `Content->Configration->Design Configuration->Edit`

**I'm getting following error:-**

**Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set**

Screenshot:-

> http://nimb.ws/kV93zH

When i R&D then found that it's M2.2.4 issue so I've to modify this method.

Here is the Module :-

**Step1:- app/code/Allin/Coreissueresolve/etc/registration.php =>**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Allin_Coreissueresolve',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step2:- app/code/Allin/Coreissueresolve/etc/module.xml =>**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Allin_Coreissueresolve" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

**Step3:- app/code/Allin/Coreissueresolve/etc/di.xml =>**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate" type="Allin\Coreissueresolve\Model\Magento\Email\AbstractTemplate" />
</config>
```

**Step4:- app/code/Allin/Coreissueresolve/Model/MagentoEmail/AbstractTemplate.php  =>**

```
<?php

namespace Allin\Coreissueresolve\Model\Magento\Email;


abstract class AbstractTemplate extends \Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate
{
     public function setForcedArea($templateId)
    {
        echo "Hello123" ; exit;
    }

}
```

After that i've run `php/bin/magento setup:upgrade`  & also `cache:flush`.

But `app/code/Allin/Coreissueresolve/Model/MagentoEmail/AbstractTemplate.php` => `setForcedArea()` is not calling.

While `vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php` => `setForcedArea()` is calling everytime.

Comment: can you try the plugin.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230721/i-want-to-override-abstracttemplate-php-of-vendor-magento-module-email-model

Comment: I've to override method so i can't use plugin here.

Comment: When I try to make changes in the `AbstractTemplate.php` file I get **open for write: permission denied
File transfer failed** Can you please help?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot override that class.
`Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate` is an abstract class and it never gets instantiated.
Your code is correct but you don't see your method being called because your class is never instantiated.
`preferences` work only for classes that get instantiated.
You can do one of the following.
 - Create an `around` plugin for the method. Plugins work with abstract classes because they will be called also in the child classes of the abstract ones.
 - Rewrite the method in every child class of the AbstractTemplate class.  I don't really recommend this since it's painful and you can easily miss something.

Comment: You should also avoid overriding an abstract class.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the plugin to make changes in this function.

Create following files in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate">
        <plugin name="email_setforced_area" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Email\Model;

class AbstractTemplate
{
    private $emailConfig;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config $emailConfig)
    {
        $this->emailConfig = $emailConfig;
    }

    public function aroundSetForcedArea(\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate $subject, \Closure $proceed, $templateId)
    {
        if (!isset($subject->area)) {
            $subject->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
        }
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! made my day!!! +1 :)

Comment: In phpstorm I see a red line with message "Member has private access" (regarding $subject->area). (Magento version 2.2.5 ).

Comment: @amitshree it works. I've just tried, even with PhpStorm nagging about the $subject->area visibility.

Answer (score 0):

same issue i faced i also want to override the file `AbstractTemplate.php of vendor\magento\module-email\Model\`
but can't.

Marius is right: "You cannot override that class.
Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate is an abstract class and it never gets instantiated."

then i override the `template.php  of vendor\magento\module-email\Model\`

adding this function `public function setForcedArea($templateId)
    {
        if (!isset($this->area)) {
            $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
        }
        return $this;
    }`
.
and issue resolved . theme easily selected after overriding the `template.php` file .

here is complete override  module you can download here and solve the problem
https://github.com/hafizjee/Area-code-is-already-set